# Setting type of fractional to num

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Could someone please explain why this compiles

```
Prelude> 1 :: Num a => a
```

and this doesn't

```
Prelude> 1.0 :: Num a => a
```

Second example would work with `Fractional`, but `Num` is superclass of `Fractional`. Just like it's superclass of `Integral`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we have

```
x :: Num a => a
```

the user of `x` can pick `a` as wanted. E.g.

```
x :: Int
```

What would this evaluate to if `x = 1.5` ?

For this reason a floating point literal can't be given the polytype `Num a => a`, since its value won't (in general) fit all `Num`eric types.

Integral literals instead fit every numeric type, so they are allowed.

Comment: thanks @chi. makes sense when you put it that way :) so `1 :: Num a => a` holds true for any `a` that's instance of `Num`, but `1.0` doesn't.

Comment: @rodic Yes. Theoretically, the designers of Haskell could have mandated that `1.0` be handled as if it were `1`, but in practice it would be terribly confusing to discover that, in a given context, `1.0` type checks but `1.5` does not. So, `1.0` was allowed only to represent values of types in the `Fractional` typeclass.

Comment: yeah, i had any float on mind when i wrote 1.0. but now i realize my original question could be rewritten like, why `1 :: a` doesn't compile. thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The superclass relationship between type classes does **not** establish relationships between types. It tells us only that if type *t* is a member of type class *C*, and *B* is a super class of *C*, then *t* will also be member of *B*.

It **doesn't** say that each value *v::t* can be used at any type that is also member of *B*. But this is what you are stating with:

```
3.14159 :: Num a => a
```

Answer (score 3):

It's important to distinguish between polymorphism in OO languages and polymorphism in Haskell. [OO polymorphism is covariant, while Haskell's *parametric polymorphism* is co**ntra**variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

What this means is: in an OO language, if you have

```
class A {...}
class B: A {...}
```

i.e. `A` is a superclass of `B`, then any value of type `B` is also a value of type `A`. (Note that any particular *value* is actually not polymorphic but has a concrete type!) Thus, if you had

```
class Num {...}
class Fractional: Num {...}
```

then a `Fractional` value could indeed be used as a `Num` value. That's roughly what covariant means: any subclass value [is also a superclass value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle); the values hierarchy goes the same direction as the type hierarchy.

In Haskell, `class`es are different. There is no such thing as a “value of type `Num`”, only values of concrete types `a`. That *type* may be in the `Num` class.

Unlike in OO languages, a value like `1 :: Num a => a` *is* polymorphic: it can take on whatever type the environment demands, provided the type is in the `Num` class. (Actually that syntax is just shorthand for `1 :: ∀ a . Num a => a`, to be read as “for all types `a`, you can have a value `1` of type `a`.) For example,

```
Prelude> let x = 1 :: Num a => a
Prelude> x :: Int
1
Prelude> x :: Double
1.0
```

You can also give `x` a more specific constraint of `Fractional`, since that's a subclass of `Num`. That just restricts what type the polymorphic value can be instantiated to:

```
Prelude> let x = 1 :: Fractional a => a
Prelude> x :: Int

<interactive>:6:1:
    No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘x’
    ...
Prelude> x :: Double
1.0
```

because `Int` is not a fractional type.

Thus, Haskell's polymorphism is contravariant: polymorphic values restricted to a superclass can also be restricted to a subclass instead, but not the other way around. In particular, you can obviously have

```
Prelude> let y = 1.0 :: Fractional a => a
```

(`y` is the same as `x'`), but you can not generalise this to `y' = 1.0 :: Num a => a`. Which is a good thing as Ingo remarked since otherwise it would be possible to do

```
Prelude> 3.14159 :: Int
  ????
```

Comment: got it. num is not a type like in oo, but set of types and in order for a val to be polymorphic it must be able to instantiate to any num type, any other rule would lead to absurd situations as you guys showed.